# Python using drop() method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame with the following columns: `TAG`, `ALIAS`, `COMMENT`, `TYPE`.

Is there a way to drop all columns that are not `COMMENT` without having to type the following line?

```
df.drop(["TAG","ALIAS","TYPE"], 1)
```

Is there a way to type an if statement somewhere in there and drop anything that is not the column call e.g., `COMMENT`?

Comment: I've misread the question so I reopened. However, if you only want to select one column, why don't you just use `df['COMMENT']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that you only want the column COMMENT, just for for

```
df = df['COMMENT']
```

If you are looking for various columns starting with COMMENT, say COMMENT1, COMMENT2 etc, you can use filter

```
df = df.filter(like = 'COMMENT')
```

As @piRsquared suggested, another method of selecting columns would be

```
df = df[['COMMENT']]
```

This would be especially needed if you want to select multiple columns

```
df = df[['COMMENT', 'COMMENT1']]
```

Comment: So I don't have add an answer `df = df[['COMMENT']]`

Answer (score 3):

I changed my mind on adding an answer.  This is obnoxious as what A-Za-z and ayhan have said makes way more sense...

... However, that doesn't stop me from posting this

```
df.drop(df.columns.difference(['COMMENT']), 1)
```